Size Row height based on Specific Child
I want to set the Row height based on the text Sign in height.
Therefore, the icon and the image logo should match this height. But it does not.

When text is small, images and icon should be smaller too.

 Container(
              color: Colors.pink[700],
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Text("Sign in", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 64)),
                    FittedBox(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.phone,
                        size: 24,
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    ),
                    // Icon(Icons.phone),
                    Image(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/logos/google_light.png',
                        package: 'flutter_signin_button',
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                      // height: 12.0,
                    ),
                    // Column(
                    //   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    //   children: [
                    //     FlutterLogo(),
                    //     // FittedBox(child: FlutterLogo(), fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,),
                    //   ],
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

Is there a simple way to achieve this without using GlobalKeys and findRenderObject or an external package ?

I commented   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch because it works when text is taller than the images/icon but when smaller, it does not work

This is the kind of thing that Boxy can solve (although it may be overkill.  See https://pub.dev/documentation/boxy/latest/flex/Dominant-class.html

I found a temporary solution but a better solution is welcome. It is not good because we have to set a height:1.0 it feels like a hack
  Container(
              color: Colors.pink[700],
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  // textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,/
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.green[700],
                        child: Text("Sign ", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8))),
                    FittedBox(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.phone,
                        size: 1,
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    ),
                    // Icon(Icons.phone),
                    Image(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/logos/google_light.png',
                        package: 'flutter_signin_button',
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                      height: 1.0,
                    ),
                    // Column(
                    //   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    //   children: [
                    //     FlutterLogo(),
                    //     // FittedBox(child: FlutterLogo(), fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,),
                    //   ],
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),


Update: A slight improvement
 ConstrainedBox( child: FittedBox(child: Icon(Icons.phone)), 
constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 0),
                    ),

